# What army are these Warhammer 40K Robots from?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I found a picture of an old advertisement for Warhammer 40,000.
It shows "ROBOTS", which resemble Terminators or Space Marines somewhat.

Here's a copy of the image:

[image]

Which army are these robots from?  Can they still be fielded in modern 40K?

Comment: Could they be [Imperial Robots](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Robots)?

Comment: Or maybe [Legio Cybernetica](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Legio_Cybernetica)?

Comment: Awww, Nostalgia!

Answer (score 6):

These are from the bygone days of Rouge Trader, when you could field Imperial Robots.  GW's fluff and art direction where less mature at this point and you got lots of random stuff like this.

Fluff wise the technology has been lost and/or declared heresy by the Imperium for millennium. [But Forge World brought them back.](http://www.forgeworld.co.uk/The_Horus_Heresy/Mechanicum/Mechanicum_Troops/CASTELLAX_BATTLE_AUTOMATA.html)

Comment: Yep, Imperial Robots. You can see examples matching the provided picture in the gallery here: http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Robots#Gallery

Comment: Are there any rules available for the Forge World model?

Comment: @ire_and_curses [It would be in one of these.](http://www.forgeworld.co.uk/The_Horus_Heresy/Horus_Heresy_Books)  Not sure which one

Comment: An issue of white dwarf (round about 104) I think introduced programming for robots whereby you would construct a sort of flow chart to determine what a robot did in any given turn depending on the conditions rather than choose what the unit did. You paid points for each component of the program. I never played them but spent ages doing what I now realise was basically computer programming optimisation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Forgeworld has been re-vamping these rules for 30k (heresy-era) games.  The only current re-vamp is the Castellax, which is a variant of the Castellan (#2 or #4 in the pic).

Comment: Are you able to answer to where exactly they're from? That's part of the question too.